# About reference to pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I've been making a tree, because planting a trees will save the planet (or just the program).

```
class Tree {
  Node* root;
  // ...
  void insert(int value){
    private_insert(value, root);
  }
  void insert_private(int value, node* n){
    if(n == nullptr){
      n = new node(value);
    } else {
      your standard recursive insertion function here
    }
  }
  // ...
};
```

Long story short i've tried using shared_ptrs first, but the the insert() function will never add any element into my tree. I thought i might be doing something wrong with shareds so i tried raw pointers and i got the same non-inserty resoults.

Turns out i need to pass a reference my root/nodes.

```
void insert_private(int value, node*& n) {...};
```

I understand that if i dont pass something as reference then a copy is made. But if a pointer holds an address, doesnt it's copy hold the same address? if i make a new() to a non-referenced pointer why doesnt it stick to my root/nodes?

The why is my question here, i can accept it that it works like this, my tree works, but i dont know why its like this.

edit: After reading the comments i created this small expert level program:

```
void fn(int* i){
  cout << "Address of local in fn before change: " << i << endl;
  i = new int(2);
// so basically here we made a new int, and i will get the address of 
// this integer and will point to there, what we passed on before 
// becomes irrelevant
  cout << "Address of local in fn after change: " << i << endl;
}
void fn2(int **i){
  cout << "Address of local in fn2 before change: " << i << endl;
  *i = new int(2);
  cout << "Address of local in fn2 after change: " << i << endl;
}
int main(){
  int* p = nullptr;
  cout << "Address of p: " << p << endl;
  fn(p);
  cout << "p& is: " << &p << endl;
  fn2(&p);

  cin.get();
  return 0;
};
```

Thank you, everyone, for the answers, it helped a lot. random.org will determine who's the one who will get the approved answer thing.

Comment: why are you passing `n` / `root` as parameter and not just change it directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's a copy and it holds the same address, but you are assigning only to the copy which is then thrown away when the function returns. The original is unaltered. That's your problem.

As an aside, IMHO, if you are altering the value of a parameter, you should use a pointer, hence a pointer to a pointer in your case. It makes it much more obvious to the reader that you're changing the value.

Comment: Don't be so humble. The last paragraph is good advice indeed (imho).

Comment: In case of C++ if you have an algorithm that expects a valid reference you should use references. If you're not going to change things use const references, non-const lvalue references if you do change stuff. Pointers should only be used when necessary.

Comment: All right, so - do correct me if iam wrong - its something like this:
i have a root with a memory address of 0x12345678 poining to null.
In my function i have the same memory address and i assign a node.
if the function ends the local copy is thrown away, what happens to the node i new-d in it on the "same address"?

Comment: Pointers may be null or may even point to some invalid address. There's no guarantee for a pointer to actually reference a valid object whereas for the reference there is.

Comment: As far as pointers being null, that's what `assert()` is for. There's no _guarantee_ that a reference refers to a valid object either. But don't take it from me, take it from [Bjarne](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#call-by-reference) (second-to-last sentence in that section). If the use of pointers-to-pointers is hard to read, you can always declare a _local_ reference to the dereferenced pointer _inside_ the function for _your_ (as the implementor) ease of reading: `node &r = *n`. The compiler will optimize that reference away.

Answer (score 2):

`n = new node(value);` is an assignment.

The pointer gets a new value. Now it points to somewhere else. The pointer was passed by value, so the calling code won't see any change - the assignment only had a local effect.

Answer (score 2):

In `insert_node` you are changing what `n` is pointing to.

If you want that to be reflected in the caller, then you need to pass the pointer `n` by reference: `void insert_private(int value, node*& n)`, although I prefer `node** n` as that signals to the caller of the function that the parameter value *might* change.

Although, since `root` is a class member, you can modify it directly within `insert_private`.

Answer (score 2):

> But if a pointer holds an address, doesnt it's copy hold the same address?

Sure, until you change the address held in the copy.

Answer (score 1):

Your design aside to the "why?": A pointer is a normal variable. Changes made to a local copy in the callee won't be reflected on the caller side.

```
void foo (int a)
{ // here: a is a copy of whatever will be passed to foo
  a = 2;
}
void foo2 (int &a)
{ // here: a is something like 'a local name' for the int passed to foo2
  a = 3;
}

int x = 0;
foo(x); // inside foo(x), a is another int copied from x
// x still 0 here
foo2(x); // inside foo2(x), a is 'a local name' for x
// x == 3 now
```

Pointers behave the same way as they're just variables containing an address.

```
void bar (int * a)
{
  a = new int;
}
void bar2(int * &a)
{
  a = new int;
}

int * x = nullptr;
bar(x); // inside bar(x), a is a new pointer copied from x
// x still nullptr here
// (and memory leaking from the new without delete)
bar2(x); // inside bar2(x), a is 'a name' for the passed pointer x
// x contains memory address from a new int
delete x;
// can be deleted -> no leak
```